# What is wrong with this PL/SQL? Bind Variable * is NOT DECLARED

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

Here is:

```
declare
  v_str1   varchar2(80);
begin
  v_str1 := 'test';
  print :v_str1;
end
```

When I run it using SQLDeveloper just in a sql worksheet I get this:

```
Bind Variable "v_str1" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed
```

Comment: What the heck is "print" ? I know of no PL/SQL command of that name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  v_str1   varchar2(80);    
begin
 v_str1 := 'test';
 dbms_output.put_line(v_str1);
end;
```

[More info here.](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ)

Answer (score 4):

The bind variables syntax of the form :VARNAME are used primarily in SQL* Plus (except for bind variables for dynamic SQL, I think).
For SQL* Developer, PL/SQL Developer, or other apps, there is the "&" for variable substitution:

```
declare
  v_str1   varchar2(80);
begin
  v_str1 := &v_str;
  print v_str1;
end
```

**EDIT:**
My bad, the code for Oracle SQL*Developer should have been:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  v_str1   varchar2(80);
begin
  v_str1 := '&v_str';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_str1);
end;
```

You have to select everything and execute it. The result will appear in the "Script Output" panel.

Comment: It prompts for a value for V_str then throws an error ORA-06550. If you change it to print :V_str1; you get Bind Variable "v_str1" is NOT DECLARED.

Answer (score 3):

`print` is not a PLSQL function. If you want to get an output, you can use `dbms_output.put_line(v_str1);`

```
set serveroutput on;    
declare v_str1 varchar2(80);
begin
    v_str1 := 'test'; 
    dbms_output.put_line(v_str1);
end;
```

:v_str1 is a bind variable but you must declare not in a plsql. When you declare it you must use VARIABLE keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
declare
  v_str1   varchar2(80);
begin
  v_str1 := 'test';
  print v_str1;
end
```