# write function in PL/SQL to Sum within the same table

Tags: sqlplus

I am trying to write a PL/SQL function name hoursWorked that takes workerId and prjId and returns total amount of hours worker has worked on a project.

Table named PROJECTHOURS

```
WORKERPRJID | WORKERID |     PRJID |  TOTHOURS |    CDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
         1          1          1         10 1-JAN-14
         2          1          1          7 2-JAN-14
         3          1          1          6 4-JAN-14
         4          2          1          5 11-JAN-14
         5          2          1          9 15-JAN-14
         6          2          1          7 13-JAN-14
         7          1          2          5 11-JAN-14
         8          2          2          9 15-JAN-14
         9          2          2          7 13-JAN-14
```

I have tried the following:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Hoursworked (j IN NUMBER,
                                         n IN NUMBER)
IS
  hours_worked projecthours.tothours%TYPE := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT workerid,
           prjid,
           SUM(tothours)
    INTO   hours_worked
    FROM   projecthours
    WHERE  workerid = j
           AND prjid = n
    GROUP  BY j,
              n;

    RETURN hours_worked;
END; 

SQL> show errors;
Errors for PROCEDURE HOURSWORKED:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/52     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
12/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
12/1     PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an
         expression
```

Admittedly I am very inexperienced with SQL in general, so any insights are very welcome, as to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select is wrong, you select 3 values, but fetch into only one. The group by references are incorrect.

You don't need to select the workerid or the project id, neither do you need the group by.

Should be like below

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Hoursworked (j IN NUMBER,
                                         n IN NUMBER,
                                         hours_worked OUT NUMBER)
IS

BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(tothours)
    INTO   hours_worked
    FROM   projecthours
    WHERE  workerid = j
           AND prjid = n;

END;
```

In a procedure Return immediately ends program execution, and doesn't expect any parameters. Either change the program unit type to a function, or use OUT variables as above.

And please give better parameter names than "j" & "n"

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip. When loading the function I still get an error: 12/5     PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an
         expression
Am I correct to think I then need to specify what I want from within the temp table?

Comment: @dan.mi.sun check my edit, return isn't needed for procedure.

Comment: SQL> call Hoursworked(1,1,1); results in ORA-06577: output parameter not a bind variable   Could you clarify how this would then get called?

Comment: @dan.mi.sun it should be `call hoursworked(1,1,:hours_worked)`. The output will then be stored in variable `:hours_worked`

Comment: If using a variable do we then need to declare the variable as per this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597806/what-is-wrong-with-this-pl-sql-bind-variable-is-not-declared

Comment: @dan.mi.sun you're using SQL*Plus, so it's not needed. If you're calling it from other programs then yes it's as per the linked question