# Plsql procedure calling in scheduler

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-apex

I have created one procedure and calling that procedure in job which runs once every 2 hours.

In my procedure, I am trying to update the table with `:app_user`, but it's not taking in procedure.

Please help me to get the app user details to update the table through procedure.

My update query is:

```
Update Workspace_Group 
Set Group_User_Count = l_members_count,
    updated_date = sysdate,
    updated_by = :app_user 
Where workspace = 'istar';
```

Comment: How would you interpret an APEX user to be in context for a background job?

Comment: A database job runs in a database. It has no idea that Apex users exist. So, why do you think that procedure, called by that job, knows :APP_USER value? If you, however, called the procedure directly from Apex page, that would be a different story and you'd know :APP_USER value. It seems that you'd have to modify UPDATED_BY value by setting it to 'JOB' or something like that.

Comment: If *"it's not taking in procedure"* means it fails compilation with [PLS-00049: bad bind variable ':app_user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597806/what-is-wrong-with-this-pl-sql-bind-variable-is-not-declared), then you will need to work out what user details are actually required and available at runtime, and code it to use those.